# how can i use variable in Google Chart Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

Below is the code:

```
                    <div id="chart_div"></div>

                        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script> 
                        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
                        <script type="text/javascript">

                            var data12 = '<%= GlobalVariable.Data99 %>';


                            // Load the Visualization API and the corechart package.
                            google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['corechart'] });

                            // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
                            google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

                            function drawChart() {

                                // Create the data table.
                                var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                                data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
                                data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
                                data.addRows([
                                ['Completed', 3],
                                ['New', data12],
                                ['Waiting', 2]
                            ]);

                                // Set chart options
                                var options = { 'is3D': true,
                                    'width': 480,
                                    'height': 200
                                };

                                var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
                                chart.draw(data, options);
                            }
                        </script>
```

I want to use **data12** variable. Chart is not displaying the variable value. data12 is a gloabl variable.

I have updated the code. Please check now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to change:

```
var data12 = '<%= GlobalVariable.Data99 %>';
```

to

```
var data12 = parseInt('<%= GlobalVariable.Data99 %>');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function drawChart() {


data12 = parseInt('<%= GlobalVariable.Data99 %>');
                                // Create the data table.
                                var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                                data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
                                data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
                                data.addRows([
                                ['Completed', 3],
                                ['New Complaint', data12],
                                ['Waiting Response', 2]
                            ]);
```

you can not enter variable in " " .because it consider as string.
note: data12  must have number value

Comment: can you please post full code so we can understand your problem

Comment: I have updated the code in question. Please check. Thanks.

Comment: hi john i think  you need to reassign the variable value in drawChart() function because it call  when page is loading. i also update my ans.